# Convert string start with 0 to 2 decimal place asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, decimal, valueconverter

I have this string:

```
Dim value as String = "0.11209176170341301"
```

And tried to use this code to convert the string into decimal with two places:

```
Dim value as String = "0.11209176170341301"
 Dim valueInDecimal As Decimal
            If [Decimal].TryParse(value, valueInDecimal) Then
                Console.WriteLine(valueInDecimal.ToString("0:0.#"))
            End If
```

I get this result:

```
11209176170341301D
```

I need to get this:

```
0.11
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I want to get as result a decimal with two placesfrom the string value

Comment: `valueInDecimal.ToString("G2");`

Comment: valueInDecimal.ToString ("#.##");

Comment: What is your Culture? Or in other words, is that `.` treated as a decimal separator, or as a "group separator"? You might want to specify the culture in the TryParse and ToString

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic string operations also:

```
    string value = "0.11209176170341301";
    var parts = value.Split('.');
    var floatingPart = parts[1].Substring(0, 2);
    var truncatedValue = parts[0] + "," + floatingPart;

    decimal d = decimal.Parse(truncatedValue);
    string s = d.ToString();
    Console.Write(s);
    Console.Read();
```

If you are only needed it as string then you can just truncate it as string then it will be easier like:

```
    string value = "0.11209176170341301";
    var parts = value.Split('.');
    var floatingPart = parts[1].Substring(0, 2);
    var truncatedValue = parts[0] + "," + floatingPart;
    Console.Write(truncatedValue);
```

Or even you do not convert '.' to ',' then it will be like this:

```
    string value = "0.11209176170341301";
    var parts = value.Split('.');
    var floatingPart = parts[1].Substring(0, 2);
    var truncatedValue = string.Join(".",parts[0],floatingPart);
    Console.Write(truncatedValue);
```

Comment: Your code works perfect to me, but I think is too code, to make a simple thing, don't you believe it?

Comment: @Esraa_92 If you only need it as string and not need to use it as decimal? Then you can just truncate it as string and use it like that

Comment: @Esraa_92 You can also use regular expressions which will be quiet shorter than this. But the thing is the shorter it does, the harder to read.

Comment: I appreciate the string is `0.11209176170341301` but what happens if it changes to `0.11609176170341301`. Would it still be 0.11 or would it round up to 0.12? To be honest I'm not sure if that would matter in this instance but just curious.

Comment: It is just truncating the string. Not like Math.Round function. so even if it was 0.1199999 it will be shown as 0.11

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.Round function

```
        var x = "0.11209176170341301";

        Console.Write(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(x), 2));
```